# Implementing cmb_field_map for cmb2

Tags: wordpress, cmb2

I'm trying to use the cmb_field_map extension by julykaz for cmb2 in a wordpress plugin to display a google map location.

https://packagist.org/packages/julykaz/cmb_field_map

Have successfully installed it into composer and action hook for cmb2_render_pw_map is registering in the page - but no field (or map) displayed.

cmb2 is installed and working correctly.  By the documentation on the page, I should just have to add the appropriate type.

I've got:

```
  $cmb_location->add_field( array(
    'name'    => 'Google Map Location',
    'desc'    => 'Drag the marker to set the exact location',
    'id'      => $prefix . 'map',
    'type'    => 'pw_map'
  ) );
```

In the admin edit page the 'name' field is display but nothing for the googlemap (or even a field).

Not sure what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 0):

Look this -> https://github.com/mustardBees/cmb_field_map Propably you've probably forgotten Google Maps API key.